# Javascript IDs into variables onchange

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

My html form works perfectly and the javascript works perfectly...the only issue is I obviously don't want to repeat the code 15 times so I need the id's to be pulled into variables.

Simply trying to get three id's from whichever form is submitted onchange. my_btn_id, my_img_id, my_input_id.  That's it.  I've tried thousands of possible syntax variations, looked up hundreds of answers in here and nothing has not worked the way I need it to.  I'm obviously missing something.  All help is appreciated.

Here is the simplified html form:

```
<form action="#” method=" post " id=”my_form_id”>
    <input type="file " id="my_input_id "><br>
    <button type="submit " value="Upload " id="my_btn_id ">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Here is javascript - the id's i'm looking for are highlighted with **

```
$(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function () {
    var input = $(this),
        label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
    input.trigger('fileselect', [label]);
});

$('.btn-file :file').on('fileselect', function (event, label) {
    var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
        log = label;
    if (input.length) {
        input.val(log);
    } else {
        if (log) alert(log);
    }
});

function readURL(input) {
    **var imgid = "#my_img_id";**
    **var btnid = "#my_btn_id";**

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(imgid).attr('src', e.target.result);
            $(btnid).show();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

**var inputid = "#my_input_id";**

$(inputid).change(function () {
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, you can't use the same IDs in multiple forms.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.  This is one form.  There are 14 others and they all have unique ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this.

```
$("#my_input_id1, #my_input_id2, #my_input_id3").on("change",function(){
   var inputItem = $(this);  
   readURL(inputItem);
});
```

You can also create variables. For example:

```
<input type="file" class="inputItem" data-img="my_img_id1" data-btn="my_btn_id1">
<input type="file" class="inputItem" data-img="my_img_id2" data-btn="my_btn_id2">
<input type="file" class="inputItem" data-img="my_img_id3" data-btn="my_btn_id2">
```

Then with jQuery

```
$(".inputItem").on("change",function(){
     var imgid = $(this).attr("data-img");
     var btnid = $(this).attr("data-btn");

     // then you can create dynamic selectors
     // ...

     $("#"+imgid).attr('src', e.target.result);
     $("#"+btnid).show();

});
```

I hope this helps or point you to the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

`$(this.form)` will return the form that contains the input element that the event was triggered on. You can then use this to find the other elements you want.

```
var form = $(input.form);
var img = form.next("img");
var btn = form.find("input:submit");
```

There's no need to get their IDs, you can just use the jQuery objects themselves. E.g.

```
img.attr("src", e.target.result);
btn.show();
```

Full code:

```
function readURL(input) {
    var form = $(input.form);
    var img = form.next("img");
    var btn = form.find("input:submit");    

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            img.attr('src', e.target.result);
            btn.show();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("input[type=file]").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  I actually have been looking at this for 3 days and I have no idea where to make these changes.   If it's possible to show me your changes within my code, that would be awesome.  If not, that's ok.  I'll sleep and look at it tomorrow. :)